# I'm unable to use transactions in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a hobby project(Shop management) with Laravel. I'm trying to use DB::beginTransaction() and DB::rollback(), but it is not working. According to my code, I believe that no entries should have populated in the DB.

I have already googled for possibilities, but couldn't find any solution.
And, my MySQL tables are InnoDB

Here is my Shop Controller file.

```
    class shopController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function getView()
    {
        if(Auth::user()->shop_status==0)
            return View::make('shop')->with('name',json_encode(Auth::user()->Vendor_Detail()->get(['first_name', 'last_name'])));
        else
            return redirect('/home');
    }

    public function addShop(ShopDataRequest $request){
    //get the logged in vendor's model instance. Auth uses Vendor model
            $vendor = Auth::user();
    //create new Shop Model
            $shop = new Shop;
            $shop->name = $request['shop_name'];
            $shop->address = $request->addressLine1;
            $shop->pincode = $request->pincode;
            $shop->phone = $request->phone;
            $shop->shop_type = $request->shop_type;

        DB::beginTransaction();
        try{            
             //save shop details
            $vendor->Shops()->save($shop);
            //throw custom Exception
            throw new \Exception('User not created for account');
        }

        catch (Exception $e){
        //catch exception and rollback
            DB::rollback();
        }


    }
}
```

Models:
1) Shop:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Shop extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $connection = 'vendor';
    protected $fillable = [
        'shop_id','vendor_id','name','address','pincode','phone','shop_type'
    ];

    public function Vendor(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Vendor','vendor_id','vendor_id');
    }

    public function Products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product')->withPivot('mfg_date', 'exp_date','active','quantity');
    }
}
```

2) Vendor

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Vendor extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $connection = 'vendor';
    protected $primaryKey = 'vendor_id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'email','phone','password',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function Vendor_Detail(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Vendor_Detail','vendor_id','vendor_id');
    }

    public function Shops(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Shop','vendor_id','vendor_id');
    }
    public function Documents(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Vendor_document','vendor_id','vendor_id');
    }
}
```

MySQL table details showing DB engine .

> mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `Name` = 'shops';
>   +-------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+ | **Name  | Engine** | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length |
>   Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free |
>   Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time |
>   Collation       | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
>   +-------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+ | **shops | InnoDB** |      10 | Compact    |    1 |          16384 |
>   16384 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |             17 |
>   2016-07-03 04:56:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci |
>   NULL |                |         |
>   +-------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+ 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `Name` = 'vendors';
>   +---------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+ | **Name    | Engine** | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length |
>   Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free |
>   Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time |
>   Collation       | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
>   +---------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+ | **vendors | InnoDB** |      10 | Compact    |    1 |          16384 |
>   16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              6 |
>   2016-07-07 00:46:08 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci |
>   NULL |                |         |
>   +---------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+ 1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was with my connection. I am using custom connection in models and not the default. And when using DB facade in Laravel I think it was using the default connection i.e. **mysql** and not the **vendor**.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Shop extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $connection = 'vendor';\\custom connection
    protected $fillable = [
        'shop_id','vendor_id','name','address','pincode','phone','shop_type'
    ];

    public function Vendor(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Vendor','vendor_id','vendor_id');
    }

    public function Products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product')->withPivot('mfg_date', 'exp_date','active','quantity');
    }
}
```

Connections in my database config file:

```
'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => 'shop',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => 'InnoDB',
        ],

        'vendor' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => 'shop',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => 'InnoDB',
        ]
    ],
```

Now, my shop controller calls transactions in following way.

```
 class shopController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function getView()
    {
        if(Auth::user()->shop_status==0)
            return View::make('shop')->with('name',json_encode(Auth::user()->Vendor_Detail()->get(['first_name', 'last_name'])));
        else
            return redirect('/home');
    }

    public function addShop(ShopDataRequest $request){
    //get the logged in vendor's model instance. Auth uses Vendor model
            $vendor = Auth::user();
    //create new Shop Model
            $shop = new Shop;
            $shop->name = $request['shop_name'];
            $shop->address = $request->addressLine1;
            $shop->pincode = $request->pincode;
            $shop->phone = $request->phone;
            $shop->shop_type = $request->shop_type;

        //getting the required connection
        $connection = DB::connection('vendor');

        $connection::beginTransaction();//calling the beginTransaction() on connection
        try{            
             //save shop details
            $vendor->Shops()->save($shop);
            //throw custom Exception
            throw new \Exception('User not created for account');
        }

        catch (Exception $e){
        //catch exception and rollback
            $connection::rollback(); //calling the rollback() on connection
        }


    }
}
```

and its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `DB::commit();` for comitting your queries. Carefully read manual https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#database-transactions

Comment: You need use after save. Before throw exception

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is not in Laravel's transaction but it is the `catch` statement.  Try to replace:

```
try {
   ...
} catch (Exception $ex) {
   ...
}
```

with the following:

```
try {
   ...
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
   ...
}
```

Note that `Exception` is different than `\Exception`.

Comment: Hi @jockih . Could you please explain what's the difference between  Exception and \Exception .

Comment: If your code is namespaced, then PHP will resolve the class relative to current namespace.  Let say your controller is `App\Http\Controller\ShopController`, then `catch(Exception)` is expecting `App\Http\Controller\Exception`.  Since you're throwing `\Exception`, then you'll also need to catch `\Exception`.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just do without transactions?

if it will not create shop inside vendor just handle Your custom exception and that's all.

db rollback is dummy function if You trying to rollback unsuccessful execution.

```
    try{            
        //save shop details
        if(!$vendor->Shops()->save($shop)) {
          //throw custom Exception
          throw new \Exception('User not created for account');
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        //catch exception and do anything You wanted (without db::rollback)
    }
```